# Can't get Cordova (1.6.1) to work

Tags: cordova, web-applications

i'm rather new with PhoneGap, so this could be an easy problem to solve. I'm just bit distracted since I recall things to work with older PhoneGap.js versions.

I'm trying to get Cordova to work. The file is initialized properly (Object "cordova" exists in JS) and event handler "deviceready" fires into cordova-1.6.1.js (have tested with alert) but the callback itself is not fired at all.

Briefly: how do I get Cordova to work in a device or in desktop browser?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what "callback" is not fired?

Comment: @SimonMacDonald the deviceready event. document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() { alert('device ready'); }, false);

Answer (score 0):

Some more details will be helpful for us to help you.

Well, as much as I can understand -

First you need to get cordova-1.6.1.js file into your www/js folder.
Add the path of the file as a script in your index.html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="[location of cordova.ios(for ios)]"></script>
```

Hope it helps.